# Вывод множественного свойства "HTML/текст" в Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет! Пытаюсь вывести множественное свойство HTML/текст в Битрикс, пробую такой вариант:

```
<?foreach($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["SVOISTVO"]["VALUE"] as $SVOISTVO):?>
  <? print_r($SVOISTVO; ?>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Результат такой:

```
Array ( [TEXT] => <p>Значение свойства 1</p> [TYPE] => HTML ) Array ( [TEXT] => <p>Значение свойства 2</p> [TYPE] => HTML )
```

Собственно теги не должны выводиться в тексте (

) и тем более не должно быть "Array ( [TEXT]" и т.д.

Как быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `echo $SVOISTVO['TEXT']`

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо так именовать переменные. Это преступление

Comment: @InDevX то что нужно, спасибо огромное! Правда выводит все равно с тегами, добавил в ["VALUE"] тильду - ["~VALUE"] и выводит как нужно. Добавьте, как ответ, пожалуйста)
Переменную так обозвал для примера только)

Comment: Также, не нужно забывать про то, что может быть выбор - HTML или текст. Если использовать только с тильдой, то даже при выбранном режиме "Текст" будет выводиться HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["PROP"]["~VALUE"]["TEXT"] as $PROP){
    print_r($PROP); 
}
```

Где PROP - ваше свойство

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]